# Javascript works in FF, but not in IE or Chrome (simple function)

Tags: javascript

It's a fairly simple function that just shows and hides different div's depending on what the user selects from a dropdown menu. Any idea why it won't work in IE or Chrome, but works in FF? Been searching everywhere and can't find any answers :(

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function show(field) {
        var val = field.value;
        if (val == "imaging")
        {
            document.getElementById("imagingDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("inventoryDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("chargebackDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("studentJobAccountDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (val == "inventory")
        {
            document.getElementById("imagingDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("inventoryDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("chargebackDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("studentJobAccountDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (val == "chargeback")
        {
            document.getElementById("imagingDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("inventoryDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("chargebackDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("studentJobAccountDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (val == "studentJobAccount")
        {
            document.getElementById("imagingDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("inventoryDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("chargebackDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("studentJobAccountDiv").style.display = "block";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("imagingDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("inventoryDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("chargebackDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("studentJobAccountDiv").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

EDIT: I call the function in a drop down menu as such:

```
<select id="reportsSelect">
                        <option value="blank" id="blank" onclick="show(this)"></option>
                        <option value="imaging" id="imaging" onclick="show(this)">Imaging Request</option>
                        <option value="inventory" id="inventory" onclick="show(this)">Inventory</option>
                        <option value="chargeback" id="chargeback" onclick="show(this)">Chargeback</option>
                        <option value="studentJobAccount" id="studentJobAccount" onclick="show(this)">Student Job Account</option>
                    </select>
```

I'd love to use JQuery as someone suggested, but I have 0 experience with it, so if you have any tips or pointers for that, feel free to help.

Also to clarify the issue, when in FireFox, when a user selects whichever option they want, it displays the correct div via the show function. In IE, when they select any of the options, it does not display anything.

Comment: How are you calling show method?

Comment: Could you explain what's not working and show us how you integrate it with your page, please?

Comment: yikes - is there a reason you can't use jQuery on your project? Would really tighten that up, and it would work.

Comment: Once you get this code working, **please** post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com to get advice on how to improve it. You can write this in ~5 lines of code.

Comment: Added in the show method how it is being used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<option>` elements are not really first-class members of the document. In many browsers, including IE, select boxes are implemented using the OS/windowing-toolkit's standard widgets, and not HTML-rendered blocks, so the `<option>` doesn't have the usual affordances of a real element. In particular, you get limited ability to style and script them.

Option elements are not guaranteed to take part in event handling; they may never generate a `click` event (and you shouldn't really be distinguishing between their activation via clicking or other means anyway). You should instead monitor the state of the select box using the `change` event on the `<select>` itself.

```
<select id="reportsSelect">
    <option value="blank"></option>
    <option value="imaging">Imaging Request</option>
    <option value="inventory">Inventory</option>
    <option value="chargeback">Chargeback</option>
    <option value="studentJobAccount">Student Job Account</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('reportsSelect').onchange= function() {
        for (var i= 1; i<this.options.length; i++) { // 1 not 0 - skip the blank option
            var option= this.options[i];
            var div= document.getElementById(option.value+'Div');
            div.style.display= option.selected? 'block' : 'none';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give a brief example of how to do that?

Comment: Don't forget to wrap that in `window.onload` or some kind of `DOMContentLoaded` function - it'll throw an error if it can't find the `select` tag

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this with jQuery, here is [a simple plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/5xVDq/) for you.

Comment: Also works well! Thanks for the info on jQuery! I'll have to learn how to use that better as well. Thanks everyone for the help!